# C++ class to save std::byte

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there any C++ class that save into a file `std::byte`s?
I have used `std::ofstream`, but a cast is needed to perform it:

```
std::byte bt{ 1 };
std::ofstream ofs{};
ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(bt), 1);
```

You see: `reinterpret_cast<const char*>`?
Is there any other C++ class that save `std::byte` without any cast?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to cast the `std::byte` to a `const char*` and not just a `const char`? The pointer has probably the size of 8 `std::byte`s. Wait you probably wanted to cast `&bt`, not `bt`, then it makes sense.

Comment: `std::byte` is a C++17 thing, what do the tags [tag:c++11] and [tag:c++14] mean?

Comment: Removed the c++11 and c++14 tags since they are not relevant for `std::byte` (as mentioned above).

Comment: I've used this cast when writing bytes to files every time. In fact, it works with writing pretty much any type as binary. Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @LeonardoGazdek `reinterpret_cast` is a red flag for code reviews. `std::byte` was introduced to make working with raw bytes more natural, using the cast seems backwards

Comment: @Joel, ys you are right, I extracted the code sample from my real code, where I have `std::vector<std::byte>>`, that's why I wrote `*`, but its not necessary in did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't like that cast, you could make your own `ofstream`:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <fstream>

using ofbytestream = std::basic_ofstream<std::byte>;

int main() {
    std::array<std::byte, 4> bytes{};
    ofbytestream ofs("bytes", std::ios_base::binary);
    ofs.write(bytes.data(), bytes.size()); // write 4 bytes without cast
}
```

Note that this is very similar to how `std::ofstream` and `std::wofstream` are defined. The second template parameter, *Traits*, defaults to `std::char_traits<std::byte>` in this case.

---

The above works in g++, clang++, MSVC and icx, which means that you'll likely not have to do more than this - but, I can't find anything in the standard that *requires* implementations to support it. If you are using an implementation where this does *not* work, you'll have to implement a `std::char_traits` specialization. Here's the outline and you'd need to fill in the implementations for the `static` functions in the trait:

```cpp
namespace std {
template <>
struct char_traits<byte> {
    using char_type = byte;
    using int_type = int;
    using off_type = streamoff;
    using pos_type = streampos;
    using state_type = mbstate_t;

    static constexpr void assign(char_type& c1, const char_type& c2) noexcept;
    static constexpr char_type* assign(char_type* ptr, std::size_t count,
                                       char_type c2);

    static constexpr bool eq(char_type a, char_type b) noexcept;
    static constexpr bool lt(char_type a, char_type b) noexcept;
    static constexpr char_type* move(char_type* dest, const char_type* src,
                                     std::size_t count);
    static constexpr char_type* copy(char_type* dest, const char_type* src,
                                     std::size_t count);
    static constexpr int compare(const char_type* s1, const char_type* s2,
                                 std::size_t count);
    static constexpr std::size_t length(const char_type* s);
    static constexpr const char_type* find(const char_type* ptr,
                                           std::size_t count,
                                           const char_type& ch);
    static constexpr char_type to_char_type(int_type c) noexcept;
    static constexpr int_type to_int_type(char_type c) noexcept;
    static constexpr bool eq_int_type(int_type c1, int_type c2) noexcept;
    static constexpr int_type eof() noexcept;
    static constexpr int_type not_eof(int_type e) noexcept;
};
}  // namespace std
```

Note that specializations of `std::char_traits`, other than those in the standard library, are not required to satisfy the requirements in the named requirement *[CharTraits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/CharTraits)*.

Comment: what would be the advantage of writing the trait (if necessary) compared to the cast. Its *nicer*, ok, but is that all?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The whole thing is just to be able to avoid the `reinterpret_cast` since that's what bothered OP - but other than that, I don't see any big benefit.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai any necessary scary boilerplate can be put in an include file where it's not just nicer, but cleaner.

Comment: I mean how does it compare to something along the line of this https://godbolt.org/z/87vcbzEez. Actually while writing I realized the difference. My way works for any output stream, but only `<<`. Your `ofbytestream` is a full blown ofstream. And if needed one can still instantiate a `basic_ostream`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes, that's true. One would need a similar typedef for other types of `std::byte` streams if that's needed. It does make it easy to read and you get all the normal stream operations on it, which may or may not be overkill.

 Sidenote: I'm looking at the gcc implementation and I can't see that they've made anything "extra" to make it work with `std::byte`. There's no specialization for `std::byte`. I wonder where it hides? :-)